# Shorter form of $var= isset($_REQUEST[ 'var' ]) ? filter_var

Tags: php

Is there any shorter form of this?

```
 $var =  isset($_REQUEST[ 'var' ]) ? filter_var($_REQUEST[ 'var' ], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ): 0 ;
```

If i use the ?? operator  I miss the filter_var processing.

And if I do not check if it is empty, I get an **undefined index[var]** error. notice

Comment: What you've currently posted in the question should also produce that notice, since you don't use `empty` or `isset`.

Comment: you are right ;-)  I changed this in my code after i posted the question. u updated the question now.

Comment: What do you mean by "shorter"? Less characters with the same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be shortened to:

```php
$var = filter_var($_REQUEST['var'] ?? 0, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Instead of applying the null-coalescing operator to the entire expression, apply it only to the argument of the function.